# problem with JPA creteria when searching for date

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, criteria

i have problem when i execute criteria query.
i have contact class with dateProperty type Date

```
        java.util.Date date1=new java.util.Date(); 
        contactSpecification.add(new SearchCriteria(column, date1 , SearchOperation.GREATER_THAN));
        Page<Contact> msTitleList = contactrepository.findAll(contactSpecification,pageable);
        return msTitleList;
```

the error :

```
         ERROR 15464 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Parameter value [Wed May 06 11:37:04 CEST 2020] did not match expected type [java.util.Date (n/a)]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter value [Wed May 06 11:37:04 CEST 2020] did not match expected type [java.util.Date (n/a)]] with root cause

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter value [Wed May 06 11:37:04 CEST 2020] did not match expected type [java.util.Date (n/a)]
    at org.hibernate.query.spi.QueryParameterBindingValidator.validate(QueryParameterBindingValidator.java:54) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.10.Final.jar:5.4.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.spi.QueryParameterBindingValidator.validate(QueryParameterBindingValidator.java:27) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.10.Final.jar:5.4.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.QueryParameterBindingImpl.validate(QueryParameterBindingImpl.java:90) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.10.Final.jar:5.4.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.QueryParameterBindingImpl.setBindValue(QueryParameterBindingImpl.java:55) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.10.Final.jar:5.4.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.setParameter(AbstractProducedQuery.java:489) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.10.Final.jar:5.4.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.setParameter(AbstractProducedQuery.java:110) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.10.Final.jar:5.4.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.criteria.internal.compile.CriteriaCompiler$1$1.bind(CriteriaCompiler.java:135) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.10.Final.jar:5.4.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.criteria.internal.CriteriaQueryImpl$1.buildCompiledQuery(CriteriaQueryImpl.java:360) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.10.Final.jar:5.4.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.criteria.internal.compile.CriteriaCompiler.compile(CriteriaCompiler.java:165) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.10.Final.jar:5.4.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:735) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.10.Final.jar:5.4.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.createQuery(AbstractSessionImpl.java:23) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.10.Final.jar:5.4.10.Final]
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor103.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
```

````
} else if (criteria.getOperation().equals(SearchOperation.LESS_THAN)) {
                predicates.add(builder.lessThan(
                        root.get(criteria.getKey()), criteria.getValue().toString()));
```
````

Comment: Why you are using `criteria.getValue().toString()` you should pass date obj

Comment: @Eklavya i know that but when i tried to parse it the method builder.lessThan() can not accept it, it must to be String in that argument.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It solved i have just to parse it to date